# Given an orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $H_0^1(\Lambda)$, construct an orthonormal basis of $H_0^1(\Lambda)^d$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, orthogonality, orthonormal

Let

- $k,d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^k$ be open
- $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$
  be an orthonormal basis of $H_0^1(\Lambda)$ and $$f^n:=\frac1d(\underbrace{e_n,\ldots,e_n}_{d\text{-times}})\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N$$

Can we conclude that $(f^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is an orthonormal basis of $H_0^1(\Lambda)^d$? That should be the case, cause $$\langle f^i,f^j\rangle_{H^1(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}=\langle e_i,e_j\rangle_{H^1(\Lambda)}\;\;\;\text{for all }i,j\in\mathbb N\;.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true even in finite dimensional space. For example, if $V$ is $n$-dimensional, $V^d$ is $nd$-dimensional, so an orthonormal basis should have $nd$-elements instead of $n$ elements.

Instead, try

$$f^k_n := (0,0,\cdots 0, e_n,0,\cdots, 0),$$

(the nonvanishing term is at the $k$-th entry). Then 
$$\{ f^k_n\}_{k=1,\cdots,d, n\in \mathbb N}$$

forms an orthonormal basis for the direct sum. Note that this is true for all Hilbert spaces. Related question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410533/direct-sum-of-hilbert-spaces)

Comment: Suppose $\Lambda=(0,1)$. Then, $$e_{ij}(x,y):=\frac2{\sqrt{1+(i^2+j^2)\pi^2}}\sin(i\pi x)\sin(j\pi y)\;\;\;\text{for }i,j\in\mathbb N\text{ and }x,y\in\Lambda$$ is an orthonormal basis of $H_0^1(\Lambda^2)$. How do we obtain an orthonormal basis of $H_0^1(\Lambda^2)^2$ from the $e_{ij}$?

Comment: All elements of the form $(e_{ij},0)$ and $(0,e_{ij})$. @0xbadf00d

Comment: So, an orthonormal basis of $H_0^1(\Lambda^2)^d$ would be $\left\{f^{ij}_n:i,j\in\mathbb N\text{ and }n\in\left\{1,\ldots,d\right\}\right\}$ with $$f^{ij}_n:=x_ne_{ij}$$ where $(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ denotes the standard basis of $\mathbb R^d$, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d You are right.